# In Windows 10, how can I rename an item located in the "New Item" context menu?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

TL;DR: I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to rename two items I've created in the New Item context menu:
[image]

Instead of showing Text Document and Text Document, I'd like them to show Deleted Document and Missing Document.

Here's the Background: I've been creating empty text files with .deleted and .missing in place of the .txt extension as for placeholders for videos that either are missing from a collection or that I've deleted because I didn't like. Up until now, I've been creating a new .txt document and then changing the extension when I name the file. But, of course, every time I change the extension, I get a message asking me to confirm that I really meant to change it. So it would be so much easier to placeholders that would automatically create a new file with the appropriate ending.

And here's what I've done so far:

- I've successfully removed unwanted items, like Word and Excel, from New Item menu.
- I've been able to add two new items to the menu that create .deleted and .missing files.
- I've even been able to give the new items custom icons.

But no matter what I've tried, the menu still refers to them both as Text Documents. All the changes I've made so far have been done by creating new registry keys for my .deleted and .missing file types and adding strings for the new file templates I've created, for the new icons, and for what I thought would give each a unique name.

I've tried several of the Menu Editors I've seen mentioned in other posts, but couldn't find a way to change the name.

But it seems like the Menu item inherits its name from the associated application. Right now, I've associated the files with Notepad, so they both appear in the context menu as "Text Document." If I don't associate an application in the registry or I associate a fake app, the menu item simply disappears. I've even tried creating of Notepad in a new location and renaming it.

Comment: They have to be somewhere on the file system. Are you familiar with Powershell? You can try searching for the file names using: `(GCI -Path 'C:\' -Filter 'Text Document' -File -Force -EA 0).FullName`. This will allow you to find any, and all files with that specific name so once found, you can probably rename them from there?

Comment: May you explain how you created the 2 entries in the menu to start?

Comment: Export the keys you created to a .reg file & edit your post to add them in a Code Block. I'm guessing you didn't create a ProgID for each extension...